# Semi-simple Lie groups are unimodular

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, haar-measure

I don't have much background in Lie theory (especially about different kinds of Lie algebras), hence I'm struggling a bit with the following:

> Every connected Lie group $G$ with semi-simple Lie algebra $\mathfrak g$ is unimodular.

We know the modular function $\Delta_G\colon G\to \Bbb{R}_{>0}$ is continuous (as for any lc group), thus a smooth Lie group homomorphism. Using the exponential map $\Delta_G \circ \exp_G = \exp_{\Bbb{R}} \circ\, d\Delta_G$ and thus it would suffice to show that $\ker(d\Delta_G) = \mathfrak g$. I guess now there is a pretty basic argument to see this (i mean, $\Bbb R$ is a pretty basic Lie algebra), but it's a bit late and I'm not too familiar with the definitions. Maybe you could help me finish this argument?

Comment: I forgot the definition of $\Delta_G$ so my answer may not make sense at all (that's why I post it as a comment rather than an answer) but from your post I gather that you expect $d\Delta_G$ to be a Lie algebra homomorphism? In that case finishing your argument is quite simple. Since $\mathbb{R}$ is one-dimensional, the kernel of the linear map $d\Delta_G$ must have co-dimension 0 or 1, so we want to rule out the co-dimension 1 case. But if $d\Delta_G$ is also a Lie algebra morphism, then this kernel is an ideal and so we want to rule out co-dimension 1 ideals

Comment: Semi-simple Lie algebras are a Lie algebra direct sum of simple Lie algebras Since simple Lie algebras have no ideals by definition, the only ideals of the semi-simple Lie algebra are direct sums of subsets of the set of its simple summands. If one of these sums have co-dimension 1, this means that one of the simple summands (the only one not in the ideal) had dimension one. To see that this is impossible we note that there is (up to isomorphism) just one Lie algebra of dimension 1 ($\mathbb{R}$ itself) and that it is not simple.

Comment: @Vincent thanks; yes $d\Delta_G$ is a Lie algebra homomorphism as $\Delta_G$ is a Lie group homomorphism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point is just that a semisimple Lie algebra is also a perfect Lie algebra, meaning its abelianization $\mathfrak{g}/[\mathfrak{g}, \mathfrak{g}]$ is trivial. So $\mathfrak{g}$ does not admit any nontrivial homomorphisms to an abelian Lie algebra, meaning $G$ does not admit any nontrivial homomorphisms to a connected abelian Lie group.

Comment: Nice this was just what I was looking for. Thanks.